# When I run my rails4.0 app with ruby 1.9.3 getting uintptr_t error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
cparser.rb:104:in `parse_ctype': unknown type: uintptr_t (DL::DLError)
```

Suddenly I am getting this error when I run my rails app. Anyone have any idea on when these kind of error will come?

```
C:/MotorolaRhoMobileSuite4.0.0/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/dl/cparser.rb:104:in `parse_ctype': unknown type: uintptr_t (DL::DLError)
        from C:/MotorolaRhoMobileSuite4.0.0/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/dl/cparser.rb:33:in `block in parse_struct_signature'
        from C:/MotorolaRhoMobileSuite4.0.0/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/dl/cparser.rb:9:in `each'
        from C:/MotorolaRhoMobileSuite4.0.0/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/dl/cparser.rb:9:in `parse_struct_signature'
        from C:/MotorolaRhoMobileSuite4.0.0/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/dl/import.rb:183:in `struct'
        from C:/MotorolaRhoMobileSuite4.0.0/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/net-ssh-2.10.0/lib/net/ssh/authentication/pageant.rb:157:in `<module:Win>'
        from C:/MotorolaRhoMobileSuite4.0.0/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/net-ssh-2.10.0/lib/net/ssh/authentication/pageant.rb:39:in `<module:Pageant>
'
        from C:/MotorolaRhoMobileSuite4.0.0/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/net-ssh-2.10.0/lib/net/ssh/authentication/pageant.rb:31:in `<module:Authenti
cation>'
        from C:/MotorolaRhoMobileSuite4.0.0/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/net-ssh-2.10.0/lib/net/ssh/authentication/pageant.rb:22:in `<module:SSH>'
        from C:/MotorolaRhoMobileSuite4.0.0/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/net-ssh-2.10.0/lib/net/ssh/authentication/pageant.rb:22:in `<module:Net>'
        from C:/MotorolaRhoMobileSuite4.0.0/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/net-ssh-2.10.0/lib/net/ssh/authentication/pageant.rb:22:in `<top (required)>
'
        from C:/MotorolaRhoMobileSuite4.0.0/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/net-ssh-2.10.0/lib/net/ssh/authentication/agent/socket.rb:5:in `require'
        from C:/MotorolaRhoMobileSuite4.0.0/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/net-ssh-2.10.0/lib/net/ssh/authentication/agent/socket.rb:5:in `<top (requir
ed)>'
        from C:/MotorolaRhoMobileSuite4.0.0/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/net-ssh-2.10.0/lib/net/ssh/authentication/agent.rb:22:in `require'
        from C:/MotorolaRhoMobileSuite4.0.0/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/net-ssh-2.10.0/lib/net/ssh/authentication/agent.rb:22:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/MotorolaRhoMobileSuite4.0.0/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/net-ssh-2.10.0/lib/net/ssh/authentication/key_manager.rb:4:in `require'
        from C:/MotorolaRhoMobileSuite4.0.0/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/net-ssh-2.10.0/lib/net/ssh/authentication/key_manager.rb:4:in `<top (require
d)>'
        from C:/MotorolaRhoMobileSuite4.0.0/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/net-ssh-2.10.0/lib/net/ssh/authentication/session.rb:4:in `require'
        from C:/MotorolaRhoMobileSuite4.0.0/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/net-ssh-2.10.0/lib/net/ssh/authentication/session.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'

        from C:/MotorolaRhoMobileSuite4.0.0/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/net-ssh-2.10.0/lib/net/ssh.rb:11:in `require'
        from C:/MotorolaRhoMobileSuite4.0.0/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/net-ssh-2.10.0/lib/net/ssh.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/MotorolaRhoMobileSuite4.0.0/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/fog-1.32.0/lib/fog/joyent/compute.rb:3:in `require'
        from C:/MotorolaRhoMobileSuite4.0.0/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/fog-1.32.0/lib/fog/joyent/compute.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/MotorolaRhoMobileSuite4.0.0/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/fog-1.32.0/lib/fog/joyent.rb:1:in `require'
        from C:/MotorolaRhoMobileSuite4.0.0/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/fog-1.32.0/lib/fog/joyent.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/MotorolaRhoMobileSuite4.0.0/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/fog-1.32.0/lib/fog.rb:41:in `require'
        from C:/MotorolaRhoMobileSuite4.0.0/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/fog-1.32.0/lib/fog.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/MotorolaRhoMobileSuite4.0.0/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/carrierwave-0.10.0/lib/carrierwave/storage.rb:5:in `require'
        from C:/MotorolaRhoMobileSuite4.0.0/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/carrierwave-0.10.0/lib/carrierwave/storage.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/MotorolaRhoMobileSuite4.0.0/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/carrierwave-0.10.0/lib/carrierwave.rb:78:in `require'
        from C:/MotorolaRhoMobileSuite4.0.0/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/carrierwave-0.10.0/lib/carrierwave.rb:78:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/MotorolaRhoMobileSuite4.0.0/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.10.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require'
        from C:/MotorolaRhoMobileSuite4.0.0/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.10.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
        from C:/MotorolaRhoMobileSuite4.0.0/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.10.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
        from C:/MotorolaRhoMobileSuite4.0.0/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.10.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
        from C:/MotorolaRhoMobileSuite4.0.0/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.10.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
        from C:/MotorolaRhoMobileSuite4.0.0/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.10.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
        from C:/MotorolaRhoMobileSuite4.0.0/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.10.5/lib/bundler.rb:134:in `require'
        from C:/Vinothini/Projects/GSS/snapshot/config/application.rb:12:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/MotorolaRhoMobileSuite4.0.0/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:43:in `require'
        from C:/MotorolaRhoMobileSuite4.0.0/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:43:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:4:in `require'
        from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 0):

After install rmagick gem only I got this error, after uninstall rmagick gem can run app.